# Java: Threading Techniques & Concepts

Tags: java, multithreading, visualization

*When using threads I sometimes visualise them as weaving together 3 or more dimensional interconnections between Objects in a Spatial context.  This isn't a general use case scenario, but for what I do it is a useful way to think about it.*

#### Are there any APIs which you use which aid threading?

#### Have you used threads in a manner which doesn't conceptualise as thread being a process?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Are there any APIs which you use which aid threading?**

You mean appart from `java.util.concurrent`? [FunctionalJava](http://www.functionaljava.org/) got some constructs which aid in concurrent programming, as described in a multipart tutorial that starts [here](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2008/06/18/parallel-strategies-and-the-callable-monad/).

**Have you used threads in a manner which doesn't conceptualise as thread being a process?**

Yes, to the extent that threads doesn't conceptualise at all. Take an asynchronous task-runner for instance. It uses threads under the covers but I don't see them and I don't care about them. They are fully managed by the task-runner.

Under the covers, it is all just threads, but when we stop caring about the individual thread and just think about them as a number of slots where you can somehow put code in and have it run for a period of time, then that is when we start to reach for a higher level of abstraction.

Agents/Actors is a common way to do this. An Actor is like a thread that has a lump of state, and then you can send it some code and say "do this to your state when you have time" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 7):

### First of all

The usual disclaimer: concurrent programming, in any language, using any abstraction level, is **hard** and **complicated** and has many risks. Take into consideration:

- Concurrent programming complicates any application by magnitude
- Unit-testing critical sections is hard, and sometimes impossible
- Reproducing bugs originating in concurrent code is **very hard** and much dependent on architecture, OS flavor, version, etc...

### Java Concurrent APIs

Java has gone a long way in making concurrent programming as easy as possible for developers. For most cases, you will see that `java.util.concurrent` has most of the abstractions you will need:

- **`Runnable`** interface and **`Thread`** object you can extend. Just throw in your code and you have a thread ready to run
- A nice set of **`Executors`**: constant pool, dynamic pool, scheduled, or whatever. Just throw a `Runnable` at it and it does the rest.
- **`Semaphore`s** and **locks** of all sorts relieve you of needing to implement common locking techniques.
- A built-in `wait()` and `notify()` API for all objects.

### Uses

The only thing left for you, as the software engineer, is to ensure you are writing **correct** code. Meaning you should be aware of the dangerous situations you might be exposing yourself to:

- **Deadlock** - a situation in which two or more threads are waiting on unordered resources, rendering an infinite waiting loop.
- **Livelock** - two or more threads which politely try to give way to the other on a shared resource but end up not taking it (consider two people in a corridor walking up to each other and constantly moving together from side to side)
- **Starvation** - a single thread taking up most or all of a single shared resource, thus depriving other threads from access to it.

## Main Point (or, when to use)

**Use threads only when concurrency will directly improve your applications behavior.**

If you are waiting on an IO/network/hardware-bound resource, **DO** spawn a thread on it so you can continue doing other stuff.

If you are just trying to elegantly split CPU-bound computations, **DO NOT** use threads. You just might end up worsening your performance.

If you do use threads, make sure you have thoroughly contemplated the risks, and triple-checked you did not miss any exceptional situations.

### Useful (Online) Resources

Fastest way to get into things is to do the [Sun concurrency tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Other than that, get a good book.

Good luck :)

Comment: IMHO As long as you stick with best practices, multi-threaded programming and debugging is fairly straight forward.  It is hard for a beginner, but if you have been developing for 15 years you have learnt what not to do.  It gets hard when you are trying to debug someone else's code who has a different way of looking at multi-processing. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Concurrency is a deep and complicated topic to cover. Books like [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) may help.

See [Concurrency Utilities Overview](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/concurrency/overview.html) for APIs on threading. [BlockingQueue<E>](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) can be useful for example.

> A Queue that additionally supports
>   operations that wait for the queue to
>   become non-empty when retrieving an
>   element, and wait for space to become
>   available in the queue when storing an
>   element.

See [CountDownLatch](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

> A synchronization aid that allows one
>   or more threads to wait until a set of
>   operations being performed in other
>   threads completes.

and [CyclicBarrier](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) for some interesting behavior.

> A synchronization aid that allows a
>   set of threads to all wait for each
>   other to reach a common barrier point.

**Edit**:
I am reading Java Concurrency in Practice now. It's very good.

Answer (score 0):

> When using threads I sometimes visualise them as weaving together 3 or more dimensional interconnections between Objects in a Spatial context.

That does sound complicated, how would you conceptualise 600 threads for example? Why not think of them as multiple threads of execution running apparently concurrently.

> Are there any APIs which you use which aid threading?

I suggest the simplest and most straight forward are the first matches you would find. http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+threads

> Have you used threads in a manner which doesn't conceptualise as thread being a process?

Since threads are not processes, I can't say I have ever thought of threads as processes. (Except on old versions of Linux) Processes don't share memory/objects by default for a start, they run completely independently (usually different programs, possibly written in different languages) They are also start differently using different APIs.

There is a view that multi-threading is complicated.  Actually I would say the opposite.  Multi-threaded programming requires you to make your code simple, easy to understood and straight forward to reason about.  While this takes experience, your aim is simplicity.